# Media запросы работают не корректно

Tags: html, css3

Верстаю одностраничник, пытаюсь адаптировать под мобильные устройства.

Указываю медиазапросы.

Половина сайта работает корректно, вторая половина сайта, в обычном размере, стало отображать, только медиазапросы, основной css не видит. 
 То есть при большом размере экрана, он отображает как для `960px`.

Код в разных файлах, css в  первом файле подключен, медиа во втором файле, то есть очередь подключения соблюдена.

Но пол сайта медиа работает нормально, ровно с середины, перетирает основной код.

```css
.reviews {
  background: #262626;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.reviews h3,
.map h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #000;
  padding-top: 4vh;
}

.conteiner_rew {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.conteiner_rew .box_rew {
  position: relative;
  width: 287px;
  height: 290px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}

.conteiner_rew .box_rew .imgBox_rew {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: inherit;
}

.conteiner_rew .box_rew .imgBox_rew img {
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: transform 2s;
}

.conteiner_rew .box_rew:hover .imgBox_rew img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.conteiner_rew .box_rew .details_rew {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.conteiner_rew .box_rew:hover .details_rew {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.conteiner_rew .box_rew .details_rew .content_rew {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.conteiner_rew .box_rew .details_rew .content_rew h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ff0;
}

.conteiner_rew .box_rew .details_rew .content_rew p {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .conteiner_rew {
    padding-top: 30px;
    display: block;
  }
  .conteiner_rew .box_rew {
    width: 287px;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .conteiner_rew .box_rew:nth-child(7) {
    display: none;
  }
  .conteiner_rew .box_rew:nth-child(8) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="reviews" id="reviews">
  <h3>Отзывы</h3>
  <div class="conteiner_rew">
    <div class="box_rew">
      <div class="imgBox_rew">
        <img src="img/ava4.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details_rew">
        <div class="content_rew">
          <h2>Стройнова Наталья</h2>
          <p>Прекрасная фирма.Очень корректгные и внтмательные сотрудники. Тур в Египет-цена, качество было оптимальное. Так держать. Спасибо.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box_rew">
      <div class="imgBox_rew">
        <img src="img/ava2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details_rew">
        <div class="content_rew">
          <h2>Анастасия Клетова</h2>
          <p>Была в этом году с ними в Турции, в Кермане. Все очень понравилось. Отель подобрали быстро, менеджер -девочка очень приветливая, напоила кофе, объяснила все подробно. Мне все понравилось!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box_rew">
      <div class="imgBox_rew">
        <img src="img/ava3.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details_rew">
        <div class="content_rew">
          <h2>Наталья Кутняк</h2>
          <p>Выражаю благодарность турагенству Tours&Tickets за подбор тура в октябре 2017 в Шри Ланку. Менеджер Любовь учла все наши пожелания по перелету, отелю, пляжу, сопровождала нас дистанционно в течении отдыха. Мы отлично провели время, привезли
            незабываемые впечатления.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box_rew">
      <div class="imgBox_rew">
        <img src="img/ava5.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details_rew">
        <div class="content_rew">
          <h2>Анжела Валентиновна</h2>
          <p>Благодаря данному турагенству ездила в Таиланд! Получила море удовольствия и впечатлений! Спасибо Tour&Tickets за помощь! Отдельное спасибо менеджеру Юлии за помощь в выборе! Рекомендую всем!!!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box_rew">
      <div class="imgBox_rew">
        <img src="img/ava6.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details_rew">
        <div class="content_rew">
          <h2>Денис Радутный</h2>
          <p>Ездили на отдых в Египет благодаря данному агенству! Всё очень понравилось! Начиная от выбора тура до окончания отдыха! Спасибо Tour&Tikets за отличное путешествие и море впечатлений!!! Будем обращаться к Вам всегда!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box_rew">
      <div class="imgBox_rew">
        <img src="img/ava7.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details_rew">
        <div class="content_rew">
          <h2>Надежда Игоревна</h2>
          <p>Выбрала и не пожалела. Большое спасибо Юлии, отличный менеджер, очень контактная и терпеливая</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box_rew">
      <div class="imgBox_rew">
        <img src="img/ava8.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details_rew">
        <div class="content_rew">
          <h2>Кристина Цуркан</h2>
          <p>Обслуживание на высшем уровне! Советую всем, не пожалеете!!!!)</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box_rew">
      <div class="imgBox_rew">
        <img src="img/ava9.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="details_rew">
        <div class="content_rew">
          <h2>Ирина Карбовская</h2>
          <p>Это агентство мне рекомендовали знакомые, а теперь я могу рекомендовать его своим друзьям. Огромное спасибо за отдых! Был супер подобран тур. Мне и ребенку очень понравился отель который нам предложила Юля. Были учтены все наши желания. Это
            был рай для ребенка!!!Море положительных эмоций!! До встречи в новом году, я обязательно к вам приду.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Проверь очередность самих медиазапросов. Недавно сам бился с этим. Штука в том, что самая маленькая ширина должна быть самой последней, иначе одно может переписать другое.

Comment: Проверила, сначала идет медиа для 1024, потом для 960

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Спасибо, это тоже есть. Все равно не работает.

Comment: @Юлия во всех html-файлах есть?

Comment: да, во всех есть